# winform application exception DragDrop occurs outside of IDE

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2008

My winform application is failing when run outside of the IDE with a dragdrop exception. The error does not occur while being run from inside the ide (VS2008). How can I trace this. I have seen mention of using JIT in the error box that is displayed post error - will this help me trace my problem?

Comment: Yeh, you can get the stack from the JIT message, then trace that down to the function call and line number that the problem occured.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know if this will be helpful, but...awhile ago I was getting DragDropException when my WinForms app was being run on a thumb drive, not a full system. The form generating the error had no drag-and-drop feature. I never figured out the problem, but I saw that a UserControl on that form had defaulted AllowDrop=true unnecessarily. Once I turned that off, the problem went away.

If your form is intended to support drag-and-drop, I'd look into on what thread the form generating the exception is instantiated. My understanding is that Microsoft's implementation of drag-and-drop is COM-based, which must be initialized in an STA thread. Putting the [STAThread] attribute before your program's entry point will accomplish this.